# regex for phone with digits and numbers

Tags: regex, notepad++

Reposting with more info.
Need to group and identify phone numbers with multiple variations of digits and letters for a search and replace. Example of variations I need to identify:

- 1-800-123-ACDE (1234) (sólo disponible en inglés)
- 1-800-ABCDEFG (1-800-123-4567) (marque 2 para recibir atención en español)
- (800) FGHI-123 (800-4567-123) (marque asterisco para recibir atención en español)
- 1-800-GHIJ-123 (1-800-345-124) (marque asterisco para recibir atención en español)
- 1-800-JKLI123 (1-800-678-5123) (marque 2 para recibir atención en español)
- 1-800-JKLI123 (1-800-678-5123, marque * para recibir atención en español)
- 1-800-AB-CDEFG (1-800-123-4567) (marque 6 para recibir atención en español)
- 1-888-GH LMNOP (1-888-67-89012 [marque 2 para recibir atención en español])
- 1-800-2-ABC-GHI (1-800-123-6789) (marque 2 para recibir atención en español)

I've tried this but only picks up 4 of the above. Is there a way to make it more inclusive?
(1-)+(\d{3})-([A-Z]|[0-9]|-)+([\s-]?)((1-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}))(\s+(.*marque.*)|\s+(.*oprima.*)|\s+(.*s)

Best,
TL

Comment: What about `^(1-\d{3}-|\(\d{3}\)\s*)([\w\s-]+)\(([\d-]+)\W+(.*)\)`? https://regex101.com/r/n6etuI/1

Comment: Why do you ask twice the same question?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
^(1-|\()(\d{3})(-|\)\s)([\w\s-]+)\(([\d-]+)([\),\s\[\(]+\w+\s*)([*\d]|asterisco)*(.*)\)
```

This will capture the potentially interesting parts of the number into capture groups in case you want to refer to them later:

- `\1` leading 1 (empty if not present)
- `\3` 3-digit 'area code'
- `\5` character-digit combination occurring before parentheses
- `\6` digits within parentheses
- `\8` digit, asterisk or word to select option (empty if not present)

See https://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/500 for an example.